# Beta regression: Monte Carlo simulations for coefficients

Tags: r, distributions, confidence-interval, monte-carlo, beta-regression

I use `betareg` betaregresion to model degradation percentage over time: `perc_degr~time`. To calculate half-life (assuming logit link fucntion), I do as follows: `th = -coef(model)[1]/coef(model)[2]`. I also used the `mvrnorm` command from the `MASS` package to do Monte Carlo simulations to get an idea of the distribution of the values and later calculate confidence intervals:

```
sims_coef = mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=coefs, Sigma=vcovmat, empirical=T)
th_sims = (-sims_coef[,1])/sims_coef[,2]
```

Now I understood that `betareg` gives me the precision paraeter `phi`. How would I incorporate this value to simulate the distribution/confidence intervals for the half-life?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "incorporate"?

Comment: @whuber I'd like to use phi to make the predictions more realistic/more appropriate for betaregression.... So far I'm assuming a normal distribution around the coefficients, and I though maybe phi can be used to calculate the CIs of the half-life...

Comment: When you calculate `coef(betareg_model)` this gives you the full coefficient vector, i.e., including the coefficients for both $\mu$ and $\phi$. And the `vcov(betareg_model)` gives you the matching covariance matrix. Then you can simulate from the combined coefficient distribution and just compute those predictions you are interested in. So for your `th` you simply discard the simulated coefficient(s) for $\phi$.

Comment: @AchimZeileis OK, thanks. So in my model `perc ~ time` I'm only interested in `coef(betareg_model)[1:2]` and `vcov(betareg_model)[1:2,1:2]` which I pass to  `mvrnorn` to get the distribution, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strategy is to simulate the coefficients from the joint normal distribution of *all* parameters, including the $\phi$ parameter. The reason is that the coefficients for $\mu$ and $\phi$ are *not* orthogonal, i.e., depend on each other. After having obtained the full simulated parameter vector, you can than compute any quanity you want from the relevant subset of parameters.

I would recommend though to use a log-link for the $\phi$ in this case because the normal approximation will typically be much better on the log-scale because the parameters are unbounded. The easiest way to achieve that is to specify a two-part formula: `perc_degr ~ time | 1` in your case, declaring that $\mu$ depends on `time` but $\phi$ is constant. Moreover, I would encourage you to consider a model with varying $\phi$ though: `perc_degr ~ time | time` where both parameters are allowed to change over `time`.

As a worked example, consider the following illustration based on a (too) simple model for the `ReadingSkills` data available in the package:

```
library("betareg")
data("ReadingSkills", package = "betareg")
m <- betareg(accuracy ~ iq | 1, data = ReadingSkills)
```

Then we can simulate 10,000 draws from the full parameter vector (using `mvtnorm` rather than `MASS`):

```
library("mvtnorm")
set.seed(1)
cf <- rmvnorm(n = 10000, mean = coef(m), sigma = vcov(m))
```

And then we can compute any quantity we want. For example, we can compute the negative ratio of coefficients for $\mu$ and compare it with the quantity at the estimated coefficients:

```
hist(-cf[,1]/cf[,2], main = "")
abline(v = -coef(m)[1]/coef(m)[2], col = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image: Histogram ratio]

In this particular model this plot looks rather bad because we have to extrapolate quite a bit. Hence I'm also showing another quantity which looks a bit more reasonable on this data set.

Let's also compute the predicted $\mu$ at regressor `iq` set to -1, 0, and 1. So we set up a suitable 10,000 x 3 matrix and compute the predicted $\mu$ with the inverse link from the fitted model object:

```
x <- matrix(rep(c(-1, 0, 1), each = nrow(cf)), ncol = 3)
mu <- m$link$mean$linkinv(cf[,1] + cf[,2] * x)
mu0 <- predict(m, newdata = data.frame(iq = c(-1, 0, 1)), type = "response")
```

The fitted quantity from the original model is also added for comparison:

```
for(i in 1:3) {
  hist(mu[, i], main = "", xlab = paste("x =", x[1,i]), xlim = c(0.5, 1))
  abline(v = mu0[i], col = 2, lwd = 2)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. In my actual model I already set phi to be variable with `time`... Also, what's the difference between `rmvnorm` and `mvrnorm`? I get very similar values...

Comment: The `mvtnorm` package has more functionality and is more robust in certain cases. Hence, I would generally prefer that over the older/simpler implementation in `MASS`.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation, will do so